# Linq to sql querying multiple columns - query help

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a text field on my screen where users can search for a few things from one input field:

1. Address
2. Postcode
3. Client name
4. ID

What is the best way to write a query that will query these columns?

How should I take the input in, should I split string on space? or comma?

User input = 67 pottors lane 99
where "67 pottors lane" is address
"99" is/could be ID

What I have so far:

```
//q = querystring
//filteredlist = extension method for the table that I am querying
//clientlist = list of clients I have passed in as a param
```

//Here is my query for

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
{
  var result = q.Trim();
   filteredlist = filteredlist
   .Where(x => x.ID.Contains(q) || x.SubjectPropertyAddress1.Contains(q)
   || x.SubjectPropertyPostCode.Contains(q)
   || clientlist.Any(y=> x.ClientID == y.ClientID && (y.ID.Contains(q) || y.Name.Contains(q))  ));
}
```

NOTE: I will make use of indexing using sql.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an idea: make an extra column in your database with all the columns you want to search for as one big concattenated string. Then do a free text search of your input string versus that field in the DB.

Since L2SQL does not support free text search, you need to do it in stored procedure in that case or do like here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706/linqtosql-and-full-text-search-can-it-be-done)

Comment: sounds interesting, I would have to look into this, only problem is though, the only small problem is I would always need to update the queried data. I heard of Lucefene, but not sure if that was a possibility? I am eventually going down the sproc route anyway

Comment: you can use a an update trigger to update the concat columns automatically

Answer (score 0):

Ouch - is there no way for you to split the input into separate fields for ID, Address, Postcode and Name?

If so, you can keep appending Where clauses, like

```
var query = filteredList;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
    query = query.Where(c => c.ID.Contains(id))
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name))
}
```

.. same for Name, address etc

Otherwise, your query resembles more of a search engine query than a RDBMS query.

Comment: lol - I could split but it will ruin my UI big time, I would rather not if I can, I am doing what you describe above + the query I have listed in my question. My query is a get request than can have multiple params, e.g. status, or type - in these instances I do exactly what you have said above, I just want my big search box to filter on address/postcode/id/companyname if I can...

Comment: How bad will my query above bite me? Is it really that bad?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a very similar thing in the past.  I split the search string on the space character and restricted it to a maximum of 6 search "words", so that the linq is still manageable.

I came up with something like the following:

```
string[] words = q.ToLower().Split(' ');
string[] wordsFixed = new string[] {"", "", "", "", "", "" };

for(int i = 0; i < 6 && i < words.Length; i++)
    wordsFixed[i] = words[i];

    var data = from item in list
                    where (item.ID + item.Name + item.Address1 + item.Address2 + item.PostCode).ToLower().Contains(wordsFixed[0]) &&
                          (item.ID + item.Name + item.Address1 + item.Address2 + item.PostCode).ToLower().Contains(wordsFixed[1]) &&
                          (item.ID + item.Name + item.Address1 + item.Address2 + item.PostCode).ToLower().Contains(wordsFixed[2]) &&
                          (item.ID + item.Name + item.Address1 + item.Address2 + item.PostCode).ToLower().Contains(wordsFixed[3]) &&
                          (item.ID + item.Name + item.Address1 + item.Address2 + item.PostCode).ToLower().Contains(wordsFixed[4]) &&
                          (item.ID + item.Name + item.Address1 + item.Address2 + item.PostCode).ToLower().Contains(wordsFixed[5])
                    select item;
```

Comment: What you have to be aware of, if this is linq to sql, is that the query needs to be translateable to sql.  e.g. string.Format won't work.